# Xubuntu 20.04 turns off the screen right away

Tags: xubuntu, lock-screen, xfce4-power-manager

After a few minutes I leave my PC on without using it my PC monitor goes black and the screen freezes. Having XFCE as DE I changed the Power Manager settings but nothing changed. I hope to be able to solve it since it is a very annoying thing.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Screensaver", LockScreen, Disable Lock Screen !

Comment: I already did it and it didn't change anything.